# php - How to exec in background multiple bash command

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash

I'm trying to run in background two bash command using **exec** function.

```
 $action[] = "/path/script1 par1 > log1 2>&1";
 ...
 $action[] = "/path/script2 par2 > log2 2>&1";
 ...
 $cmd = "( " .implode(' && ',$action). " ) &";
 exec($cmd);
```

**script1** and **script2** are bash scripts.

Scripts are properly executed and their output is correctly saved in their log files, but my application hangs. It seems that last **&** doesn't work.

I have already tried:

```
 $cmd = "bash -c \"" .implode(' && ',$action). "\" &";
```

If I run a single command, it works in background.

I captured **$cmd** and if I run:

```
 ( /path/script1 par1 > log1 2>&1 && /path/script2 par2 > log2 2>&1 ) &
```

from command line, it works in background.

I'm using Apache/2.0.52 and PHP/5.2.0 on Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 3 (Taroon Update 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is hidden in the [PHP exec documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

Add a redirection to the top level of your command line:

```
exec( "bash -c \"( ./script1 par1 > log1 2>&1 && ./script2 par2 > log2 2>&1 ) \" >/dev/null 2>&1 & " );
```

and without `bash -c`:

```
exec( "( ./script1 par1 > log1 2>&1 && ./script2 par2 > log2 2>&1 ) >/dev/null 2>&1 & " );
```

Tested with PHP 5.3.3-7 (command line invocation): Program hangs before adding the redirect operators, and terminates afterwards.